# Star schema Sales and goal

Tags: dimensions, star-schema, fact-table

I have a star schema, the fact table is sales I  have a product, region date dimension (date, year, month, day).
Now I have a file that contains goals of sale by year and month , Now i need to compare the goal of sale with the real value (from sale fact).
But I did not know what I should do I already have my sale_fact with its dimension ,Now
I am thinking of creating a new fact table goal with 2 dimensions year and month ( is it a good idea) But how will I compare it with the sale (fact sale) they won't have the same dimension.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, create a 2nd fact table for targets, this would be attached to a month dim (containing month and year data) and whatever other dimensions are relevant.

You then have to query the 2 facts by equivalent dimensions and compare the 2 result sets. For the sales fact table you would need to aggregate it by at least month to get it to align to the goals fact table; though you could, of course, create a sales monthly aggregate fact table to improve performance if necessary

Comment: Thank you ,So I should create a new fact sale table that has only  year, month as dimension .the same as the goal fact table.

Comment: No, not necessarily. You only need to create an aggregate fact table for performance reasons i.e. querying your existing fact table and grouping the data by month is too slow.